# Rails form_with method: get cannot update a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using form_with of rails5, I want to show current time text by clicking GET button. But text isn't updated.

Though I press the button,
[image]

Text isn't updated.

[image]

Text in response is updated.
[image]

users_controller.rb is following.

```
require 'date'
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @message = Time.now.to_s
  end
end
```

index.html.erb is following.

```
<div><%= @message %></div>
<%= form_with method: :get, url: users_path do |form| %>
    <%= form.submit 'SUBMIT'%>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'LINK', { :controller => :users, :action => :index } %>
```

Please, tell me how to update text by current time.

**NOTE:**

When press a link(rendered by link_to helper method), text is updated.

press link...

[image]

then text is updated.

[image]

why I can update text by link?

**EDIT:**

Server log when clicking the button is following.

```
Started GET "/users?utf8=%E2%9C%93&commit=SUBMIT" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-17 19:13:32 +0900
Processing by UsersController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"SUBMIT"}
  Rendering users/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 153ms (Views: 112.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you add the log from log file when u click on Submit button?

Comment: Show the server logs for button click.

Comment: `form_with` syntax is not correct probably, please check it with` form_tag`.

Comment: or try this syntax `<%= form_with url: users_path, method: :get do |form| %>`

Comment: you sure it is hitting `index` action when clicking the button?

Comment: why is form submitting as js request `Processing by UsersController#index as JS` as you haven't added remote: true with form_with ?

Comment: @Gabbar I just found this out, but seems like `form_with` defaults to `remote: true` as you could see [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
<%= form_with method: :get, url: users_path, local: true do |form| %>
```

### Explanation:

I noticed in your logs

> Processing by UsersController#index as JS

which means that the form is submitted with `format: :js` because `form_with` now defaults to `remote: true` as you could see [HERE](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) (you can't do `remote: false` however, but instead use `local: true`), unlike `form_for` and `form_tag` where `remote: false` by default, but you specify `remote: true`.

Comment: No problem at all! :3

Answer (score 1):

```
<div><%= @message %></div>
<%= form_tag(users_path, method: :get) do%>
    <%=submit_tag 'SUBMIT'%>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'LINK', { :controller => :users, :action => :index } %>
```

Or

```
<%= form_with url: users_path, method: :get do |form| %>
  <%= form.submit 'SUBMIT'%>
<%end%>
<%= link_to 'LINK', { :controller => :users, :action => :index } %>
```

Comment: Because OP is using Rails 5, I believe that `form_tag` and `form_for` is already going to be deprecated soon, in favour of `form_with` which was initiated by [DHH in this discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25197), of which was implemented and merged from this [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26976).

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario In that case i had already suggested OP to use form_with with correct syntax in comment.

Comment: @Gabbar Thank you for your answer. Although I tried the second code, it doesn't work. But, I tried local: true which you mentioned in comment, then it work!